# Network X remove nodes with one edge

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I would like to remove nodes with one edge/ no edge.
I have a graph similar to below[image: Before]

[image: After]

and what I want is.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you want to remove all nodes with degree lower or equal to one.
If it's the case you can do for example :

```
import networkx

G1 = networkx.Graph()
G1.add_edges_from([('a','b'),('b','c'),('c','e'),('c','d'),('c','f'),('c','g')])
to_be_removed = [x for  x in G1.nodes() if G1.degree(x) <= 1]

for x in to_be_removed:
    G1.remove_node(x)

print(G1.edges())
```

and you'll get :

```
[('b', 'c')]
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Graph.remove_nodes_from()](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.remove_nodes_from.html#graph-remove-nodes-from) method allows you to to pass an iterable, eliminating the need for the for loop. Following the example [above:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59354345/16929109)

```
to_be_removed = [x for  x in G1.nodes() if G1.degree(x) <= 1]
G1.remove_nodes_from(to_be_removed)
```